# searching for key words in rows and marking them in a new column in r

Tags: r

[image]

I am wanting to look through the the unit column and the POSN column to see it the Unit has a MSTC and mark a 1 in a new column for all the Units that has an MSTC.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution in base R would go something like the following code snippet. This solution only does exact matching. If you're looking for partial matches or pattern matching try `pmatch` or `grep`.

```
dfrm <- data.frame(Unit = c("Arista", "Clearwater", "Kodiak"),
                   POSN = c("MST2", "MSTC", "MST3"))
dfrm$mark <- 0
dfrm$mark[dfrm$POSN == "MSTC"] <- 1
```

A tidyverse solution would be

```
library(tidyverse) # actually only dplyr required
dfrm %>% mutate(mark = if_else(POSN == "MSTC", 1, 0))
```

EDIT: Thank for clarifying the question. When you want to mark all Units that (in some row) may have contained "MSTC" in POSN you could do sth like the following:

```
to_mark <- dfrm$Unit[dfrm$POSN == "MSTC"]
dfrm$mark <- 0
dfrm$mark[dfrm$Unit %in% to_mark] <- 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer and it work...ish. I need all the Unit rows with a MSTC to be marked with a 1.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean: Do you actually have entries that contain 'MSTC' in the Unit column or what are you looking for exactly - maybe with an example. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I didnt know how to word it. If the POSN column has an MSTC i would like to mark all rows from that unit with a 1 in a new column.

Comment: Ah ok - I see now. Hope the edit helps